# Terminal Server Licensing with citrix?

Tags: terminal-server, citrix, xenapp, licensing

We are installing Citrix XenApp 6.

Our plan is to have a "citrix control" server to serve as license server and print server, and 2 citrix servers with Microsoft Terminal Sever service installed.

Now, my question: the 2 terminal servers are asking for serial and activation, which is OK, but can we install the Terminal Server Licensing service on "citrix control" server so that the 2 terminal servers will use the licenses from the "citrix control" server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're a few versions back on Citrix PS 4.0.  In our system we run the Citrix license server on a separate server and TS Licensing server runs on a domain controller.  I think at some point the TS Licensing server would only run on a DC.  This now reminds me I might want to look at putting that on the same server as the Citrix license server.

Comment: You don't need a DC to run the current RDS License server.

Comment: the DC will always be there, I just made it on the same server where the Citrix License manager is installed :-) and it works, Thanks allot

Answer (score 1):

I cant really tell from your question if you're asking if you can host the TS license server in the "Citrix Control" server or not, but your best bet with any licensing questions is to go back to the manufacturer and check with them on the specifics of your configuration. You're loading up what I think is the latest XenApp so you s hould have some support from Citrix. At the very least I'd give them a call. If you just purchased your RDS licenses then Microsoft should help you out there as well.

Comment: well yes my question is if I can host the TS license server in the "Citrix Control" server or not, it seems I can, but how I can configure the TS Servers to use this server "Citrix Control"

Comment: I believe its in the RD License Manager, you just need to point that to your license server.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Terminal Server Licensing on the Citrix License Server without problems.  We have run that way for a while.

The best way to point the rest of your domain to the TS License Server is to use GPO...

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737644(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_gp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737644%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_gp)